# How to sort an array of objects which hold again an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, javascript-objects

How to sort an array of objects which hold again an array of objects and I want to sort it by their last timestamp.

```
 var weather = [{
    city: 'New York',
    status: 1,
    response: [{
        name: 'Example', lastTimestamp: '2017-12-19T12:43:14.000Z',
        name: 'Example2', lastTimestamp: '2017-12-19T12:42:14.000Z'
    }]
  },
  {
    city: 'Chicago',
    status: 1,
    response: [{
        name: 'Example', lastTimestamp: '2018-05-10T09:00:00.000Z',
        name: 'Example2', lastTimestamp: '2018-05-10T09:04:00.000Z'
    }]
  }
]
```

In return I want the sorted object like this

```
 var weather = [
  {
    city: 'Chicago',
    status: 1,
    response: [{
        name: 'Example', lastTimestamp: '2018-05-10T09:00:00.000Z',
        name: 'Example2', lastTimestamp: '2018-05-10T09:04:00.000Z'
    }]
  },
  {
    city: 'New York',
    status: 1,
    response: [{
        name: 'Example', lastTimestamp: '2017-12-19T12:43:14.000Z',
        name: 'Example2', lastTimestamp: '2017-12-19T12:42:14.000Z'
    }]
  }
]
```

Comment: Use `array.sort` with a custom function that checks `lastTimestamp`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort array of objects by string property value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript)

Comment: it largely depends on how the sort criteria is based if there is more than one record in `response`. Besides, the `response` elements format is invalid, you probably forgot to add the object notation. That said, you should just use the `sort` prototype with the custom callback.

Comment: `[name: …` is a syntax error, since JS arrays cannot have named keys, but only numerical keys.

Answer (score 1):

This might work. It sorts by the `city` name and if they are equal they are sorted by the `lastTimestamp`.

```js
var weather = [
    {
        city: 'New York', status: 1, response: {name: 'Example', lastTimestamp: '2017-12-19T12:43:14.000Z'}
    },
    {
        city: 'Chicago', status: 1, response: {name: 'Example', lastTimestamp: '2018-05-10T09:00:00.000Z'}
    },
    {
        city: 'New York', status: 1, response: {name: 'Example', lastTimestamp: '2017-12-20T12:43:14.000Z'}
    },
    {
        city: 'Chicago', status: 1, response: {name: 'Example', lastTimestamp: '2018-05-09T09:00:00.000Z'}
    }
];

weather.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.city>b.city ? 1 :
            a.city<b.city ? -1 : new Date(a.response.lastTimestamp)-new Date(b.response.lastTimestamp)
})

console.log(weather);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *sort* method of Array:

```
weather.sort(function(obj1, obj2){
   return obj1.response.lastTimestamp < obj2.response.lastTimestamp ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sort with your own function. It should look like this:

```
weather.sort( (a,b) => {
    return new Date(b.response.lastTimestamp) - new Date(a.response.lastTimestamp)
});
```

Comment: No need of `getTime()`